# how to confirm all the payslips of paybatches in odoo 11

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-11

I am working on Odoo 11 and I have generated payslips of all employees and now I want to compute and confirm all the payslips of batch at once. Is there any option in Odoo 11 ? I search a lot but i did not found any thing. Is it possible or not in odoo?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this free module : 
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/hr_multi_payslip_confirm/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no any inbuilt option in odoo-11 for this scenario.